# How to select appropriate capacitor for an H-bridge

Tags: capacitor, motor, brushless-dc-motor, h-bridge, motor-controller

**PROBLEM:** Considering the figure below, I need to select an appropriate bank of capacitors for a 3 half-bridge brushless controller, which system have this characteristics:

- VM = 60v (maximum);
- Max Current = 100A;
- PWM frequency: 100khz;
- Rds(on) typical is 1.15mOhm;
- Rshunt = 1.0mOhm.

**QUESTIONS:**

1- What SMD package is recommended to use for these capacitors? (I'm considering to use 1206 or 1210)

2- For the capacitance, the higher the better?

3- For the number of capacitors, the more the better?

4- How to calculate a proper C for the capacitors?

[image]

**LAYOUT INTENTIONS:**

The bulk caps will be placed as shown below, in order to get the minimum current loop:

Top Layer:

[image]

3D View from Top Layer:

[image]

Comment: Package doesn't matter that much unless you plan on soldering it by hand, in which case definitely avoid anything smaller than 0603 and probably avoid some larger ones too, depending on your soldering skill.

Comment: @Hearth, the problem with the larger ones are the high impedance with the frequency increase. But in parallel, they will reduce ESR a lot, but not ESL, if I'm right.

Comment: ESL goes down in parallel too, to a first approximation.

Comment: Oh, it's also worth knowing there are "inverse" packages like 0612 and 1012 that have the contacts on the long side, which also reduces both ESR and ESL.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Do you know how to get a calculation for this situation? Just to properly project it safely.

Comment: ESL will be divided by the number of capacitors in parallel, assuming they're identical. Same as with ESR.

Comment: PCB layout matters a lot also.  Make sure those "bulk" caps are placed as close to the bridge as possible.  https://epc-co.com has some good appnotes one reducing the current loop and inductance in the layout.

Comment: I've uploaded a pic of my "layout intentions": Place the bulk caps really close to the power rails.

Comment: I don't see any layout stuff.

Comment: You haven't told us what role these caps play in the design. But if these form the DC link capacitor for a 6 kW motor driver, I don't think 1210s are in the right ballpark...

Comment: @Aaron, I've updated again (last time an error occurred).

Comment: @BrianDrummond, they are caps for DC reinforcement, to supply power while the power supply (say a battery) can't because of the series inductance of the power supply. What do you suggest for SMD caps?

Comment: I just hope you have multiple big electrolytics as well as those 1210s.

Comment: I've found some 2220 ones model [C5750X7S2A156MT](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/TDK/C5750X7S2A156MT/?qs=%2Fha2pyFadugZxqtzL8uZgZbB7PvMwnr85nx%252BSksLGce40NxyN3XRdw%3D%3D). Are them ok? I would add as much as I can, If it's a good strategy.

Comment: In general terms, the more parallel caps the better. It reduces ESL and ESR. It also provides more charge while the power supply is overcoming the local inductances.

The equation to use is \$I=C\frac{dv}{dt}\$

Comment: @Aaron, to use the capacitor equation, I need to know what amount of time to consider. For how long the capacitor will in fact provide current to the bridge? Is 1us reasonable?

Comment: You put in the amount of time and the amount of voltage change you can tolerate in the circuit.  This equation doesn't account for on board inductances and resistances. For that you'll need to do a simulation as it can get complicated pretty quick. As a reference, you circuit looks about what we do for 20-30A drives.  But you should test it. It's all about keeping the loop inductance low.